# Reading from Core Data

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

I want to read some data from Core Data for statistics. My datamodel is like in the tutorials found in the internet (a bit of clicking and voilà it is ready). But now I want to work with the data.

My function:

```
-(int)calcAve {
    int ret=0;
    ret = [[stats valueForKey:@"aveScore"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d",ret);
    return ret;
}
```

`stats` is the object connected from the .xib to the class, which. This object is bound to the entity Stats in the datamodel. `[stats entity]` returns the correct value.
`aveScore` is one object in the entity `stats` (no misspelling, checked it multiple times!).  No the error shows me, that `stats` is not the correct datamodel:

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
```

What is wrong with this? Is there a simple way to read out the data from Core Data?

Comment: You can show the contents of all the attributes in `stats` by issuing `NSLog(@"stats: %@",stats)`. What does this give you?

Comment: Output: `stats: <StatsArrayController: 0x448e20>[entity: Stats, number of selected objects: 1]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you managedObject in this case is. However usually you want to store more than one managedObject of the same class in a managedObjectContext. For example several recipes objects in a MOC. Every recipe has the properties.

Your call for value for key sounds reasonable. Check what that class of the stats object is. If it is not of the class `NSManagedObject` or your custom subclass of it you have a problem. You can only store `NSManagedObjects` within CoreData. You can check it like this:

```
NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([stats class]);
NSLog(@"class name: %@",className);
```

The way you are asking I suggest you try to read the CoreData docs again and look at the Recipes example in Apple's sample code library.

Comment: The class of `stats` is `StatsArrayController` which is a subclass of `NSArrayController`. So there could be one problem. I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: There is a problem. You want your managed object back not the array controller. You get an array of your managed objects by using [stats content], but that is usually not how to retrieve your data. Usually you generate and execute a fetch request on your moc with a predicate defining which objects to fetch.

Comment: And remember: CoreData is not a database.